# What's the proper way to calculate credit in a commercial chat room?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, signalr

I'm working on a project which provides users to chat with experts in private chat rooms. 
Users buy credits to chat with experts and they will be charged at the end of the every chat session based on the minutes they've talked. Each expert has different credit rate for every minutes of chatting.

A timer starts counting up at the begining of the chat session and users being notified at regular intervals about the total time they spend on chat room and current total credits of the current chat session. These calculations have to be made on the server side and be saved on the database. Btw chat session can be pause / resume by expert.

---

Here is a simple scenario... 
User currenty has: 10 Credits
"Expert A" demands 2credits / per minute

```
CurrentTime Event       Timer       Credit
```

- 10:40  Chat Session Starts   <kbd>00:01 min</kbd>   <kbd>2credits</kbd>
- 10:41  They are chatting     <kbd>00:02 mins</kbd>   <kbd>4credits</kbd>
- 10:42  Expert on idle        <kbd>00:02 mins</kbd>   <kbd>4credits</kbd> (Chat pauses)
- 10:45  Expert becomes online <kbd>00:02 mins</kbd>   <kbd>4credits</kbd> (Chat resumes)
- 10:46  They are chatting     <kbd>00:03 mins</kbd>   <kbd>6credits</kbd>
- 10:46  Client ends session   <kbd>00:04 mins</kbd>   <kbd>8credits</kbd>

Client will be charged for 8 credits.
He has remaining 2 credits.

> Chat Sessions will be charged at the beginning of the new minute,
>   calculations will be made based on minutes, seconds will be omitted.

---

My question is how to make these calculations on server side for every chat sessions being talked currently in a proper way?

My current approach is;

> A server side timer ticks on every 15 seconds, gets the current chat
>   sessions being talked,
>
> For every chat session :  if chat session is not paused, then adds 15
>   seconds to the timespan of the session, and then calculates the total
>   credits of current session, if user is about to running out of credit,
>   notifies him, if he already run out of credit, then end current chat
>   session. Save these transactions to the database. Update the chat
>   session clients.

But there are some pitfalls on this approach. For example, if chat session started now and timer ticks in 2 seconds, then it adds 15 seconds to the total timespan of the current chat session so it makes miscalculation. 
If I decrease the timer's tick interval, then there may be 500 current chat sessions being talked, and the timer tick interval will not be enough able to calculate every chat sessions credits in 10 seconds for instance.

Is there a better way to handle this? 
All suggestions are welcome.

By the way, I am using Asp.net MVC4 C# and Signalr to handle real time chat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to get an accurate measure of what time the chat started/stopped/paused/resumed. If the chat system you're using doesn't provide that, then perhaps every second (or few seconds) you could store a list of all active chat sessions, and use this data every 15 seconds to do the more expensive work to fully process everything. Beware that if you can't process your current load in 10 seconds, then it only has to increase by 50% and you won't be able to do it in 15 seconds either. So you might soon have to look at making it more efficient, or otherwise adding capacity.

Comment: Why make these calculations run in a batch?  I would think it would be much simpler to make it event driven: every _n_ times a message is sent through the chat program (either from expert or user), check the total time spent and calculate credits and act accordingly on them from there.  That way, it's per-chat-session, and more precise and scales easier than bulk analyzing all sessions.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein There are tons of different cases, such as If expert does not write for 2 mins or more, then pause the chat session. So I have to use a timer I think. Probably, I will not be able to detect if user runs out of credit if someone does not write for 2 mins on your approach.

Comment: You can make the chat on one side or the other the "master" for counting time. If a user asks a question and the expert never responds, there really shouldn't be any charge. Once the expert responds, you can use the timestamp of that response to calculate the current chat length, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's essential that you not perform your operations in bulk.  As you stated, you get problems with the precision of how to charge.  And I'm sure you're realizing that scaling rapidly becomes an issue.  It's much better to make it all event driven.

As I suggested in comments, part of this entails simply calculating the time used exactly.  That's easy to do - store the start time (or the expert's start time, depending on your preference), and subtract it from the end time, and bill accordingly.

Issues this can bring up:

- *When is the end time?*  That's when the chat program closes, either through session timeout, expert ending, or user ending.  Depending on your billing structure, I would advocate for making the end time in this context also include session pause.  For the purpose of calculating costs, each start-pause iteration can be counted discretely (though ideally, they'd be grouped together on a billing summary).  You could check every time a message is sent to see if the user still has credit.
- *What about idle time?  How do we account for the user idling for more time than they have, between messages?*  It shouldn't matter, really.  Next time a message is sent, you can tell them they're past due.  They may get annoyed that they spent a few minutes typing a message that won't get sent, but there are ways to avoid that.

  - If you do check the billing every time a message is sent, it's easy to note when they're running low, and issue a warning.
  - Here's a totally different way of thinking of the billing: once the session starts, your server can calculate based on rate and balance how long the session can last.  Unless there's a stop or pause event before that, you know exactly when they'll run out of credit, and if there is a resume from a pause, you can recalculate based on the remaining time.

What I would actually suggest you do is based off of that last bullet point.  At start or resumption of session, calculate based on the credit when the session will expire.  Maintain the sessions in an ordered list, sorted by the expiration time.  Then, your server side has it easy - check if time is after any session expiration times.  If it is, push an end notification.

On re-reading your requirements, my idea may be too passive for what you need.  One question is how critical is it for all calculations to be server side?  I would advocate for the client keeping a session timer and a cost calculator running, just so the user could see it without client/server traffic.  The server itself would still be responsible for the billing side of things, though.

Otherwise, if you must push notifications for time and balance, I'd still make it be done on an individual basis, instead of in bulk operations.  You could update on every message and add in a timer for each chat.  Reset the timer every time there's a message, otherwise, when the timer triggers, send a time and balance update.  Or if you don't have the resources for that many timers, do the same idea with the sorted list - update the list each time there's activity, and have it sorted on the last active time + 15 seconds.  The ones at the top of the list may need to get time and balance updates pushed.

In any case, I would focus on the idea of sending the time and balance with every message, and find a way to make it work from there.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your detailed solution description. Your sorted list solution will not probably be a good way to go since clients will not buy credits for each chat sessions. They can consume their credits as much as they want. I've added a simple scenario on my question. My approach does not make sense since it is not scalable as you stated. I had concerns about adding timer for each chat, but i'll consider that.

Comment: I won't push too hard on this point, but I do want to mention that my solution doesn't assume credits are bought per chat session.  Just that given the number of credits a user has, and the cost per session, you can calculate the maximum time available.  In your sample scenario, you can tell at the start of the session that the user will have 5 active minutes maximum with the expert.  I'm not sure what to do with it, but it's also good to see you're billing per minute.  In that case, 15 seconds of precision is sufficient, and you just have to worry about scalability.